# Struggling to get my switch statement to work

Tags: c++, switch-statement, cin

I'm trying to create a c++ program to return a a number (spelled out) when the user enters an integer value betwwen 0 and 9, can anyone work out where I've gone wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    int numinput;
    string numberWritten;

    cout << "Enter a whole number between 0 and 9" << endl;
    cin >> numinput;

    switch (numinput) {
    case 0:
        numberWritten = "Zero";
        break;
    case 1:
        numberWritten = "One";
        break;
    case 2:
        numberWritten = "Two";
        break;
    case 3:
        numberWritten = "Three";
        break;
    case 4:
        numberWritten = "Four";
        break;
    case 5:
        numberWritten = "Five";
        break;
    case 6:
        numberWritten = "Six";
        break;
    case 7:
        numberWritten = "Seven";
        break;
    case 8:
        numberWritten = "Eight";
        break;
    case 9:
        numberWritten = "Nine";
        break;
    default: "Not a number I know";

    return numberWritten;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say "to return a number", return the number *to what*? Do you want to *output* the number?

Comment: What you `return` from `main()` must be an `int` and the lowest order bits of it will become the process exit status, which (e.g.) a shell will make available as `$?`. You most likely wanted to print the finding instead, as in `std::cout << numberWritten << std::endl;`. Also, your `default:` case makes no sense; it has no effect. Also, `using namespace std;` is an antipattern and a bad habit. Last but not least, your `return` statement (even if it was meaningful) is nested incorrectly; the `std::cout` output you need to replace it with must be outside the `switch` block.

Comment: The portable return values from `main` are `0`, `EXIT_SUCCESS`, and `EXIT_FAILURE`. Returning `0` is equivalent to returning `EXIT_SUCCESS`. Returning any other value leaves you at the mercy of your compiler. Returning a `std::string` object won't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the `switch` with an array:

```
static const char * numbers_text[] = 
{
  "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four",
  "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine",
};
//...
    cout << "Enter a whole number between 0 and 9" << endl;
    cin >> numinput;
    if ((num_input >= 0) && (num_input <= 9))
    {
        cout << numbers_text[numinput] << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "Unsupported number.\n";
    }
```

The array or lookup method avoids any issues with a `switch` statement.

Fewer lines of code, fewer chances of injecting mistakes.

Comment: Ah, I haven't come across arrays yet, will look into them, and try your correction! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't return int if `int main()` return string or simply said by the compiler:

`no suitable conversion function from "std::string" to "int" exists`

this is how you fix it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int numinput;
    string numberWritten;

    cout << "Enter a whole number between 0 and 9" << endl;
    cin >> numinput;
switch (numinput) {
    case 0:
        numberWritten = "Zero";
        break;
    case 1:
        numberWritten = "One";
        break;
    case 2:
        numberWritten = "Two";
        break;
    case 3:
        numberWritten = "Three";
        break;
    case 4:
        numberWritten = "Four";
        break;
    case 5:
        numberWritten = "Five";
        break;
    case 6:
        numberWritten = "Six";
        break;
    case 7:
        numberWritten = "Seven";
        break;
    case 8:
        numberWritten = "Eight";
        break;
    case 9:
        numberWritten = "Nine";
        break;
    default:
        numberWritten = "Not a number I know";
        break;
}
    if(numinput >= 0 && numinput <= 9) {
        cout << "The number you entered is " << numberWritten << endl;
    } else {
        cout << numberWritten << endl;
    }
    cout << "The number you entered is " << numberWritten << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I apologize I forgot to test the default now it works perfectly.

Comment: This is great, thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The switch will never arrive on the

```
return number
```

As it's still inside of the curly braces. In the switch it'll stop on the *default*.

Your function is **int** main and you're trying to return a **string** with numberWritten.

This way it works

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int numinput;
string numberWritten;

cout << "Enter a whole number between 0 and 9" << endl;
cin >> numinput;

switch (numinput)
{
case 0:
    numberWritten = "Zero";
    break;
case 1:
    numberWritten = "One";
    break;
case 2:
    numberWritten = "Two";
    break;
case 3:
    numberWritten = "Three";
    break;
case 4:
    numberWritten = "Four";
    break;
case 5:
    numberWritten = "Five";
    break;
case 6:
    numberWritten = "Six";
    break;
case 7:
    numberWritten = "Seven";
    break;
case 8:
    numberWritten = "Eight";
    break;
case 9:
    numberWritten = "Nine";
    break;
default: "Not a number I know";
}

cout << numberWritten << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, at this early stage of my learning, those smaller details are more important than I thought intially! Thanks

Comment: Specially on low code language every single detail counts. Good learning! C++ is hard, but it's worth it